# Sort a list by number and char

Tags: list, sorting, lisp, common-lisp

I have the list in LISP:

```
((1 b) (1 a) (2 D) (1 z) (1 t) (2 a) (3 n))
```

I have to order it first on the number and if equal on the lexichographic order of the char, the output should be:

```
((1 a) (1 b) (1 t) (1 z) (2 a) (2 d) (3 n))
```

I have tried to sort on one parameter and then the other, how can I compose the two function ?

```
;;(sort '((1 b) (1 a) (2 D) (1 z) (1 t) (2 a) (3 n)) #'< :key #'car )
;;(sort '((1 b) (1 a) (2 D) (1 z) (1 t) (2 a) (3 n)) #'string< :key #'second )
```

Are there easier ways to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: write a comparison function which compares two-element lists in the way you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As coredump says, since you really need a list comparison function, a nice approach is do the meta thing: don't write one, but write a function which makes functions which compare lists.  Here is such a function:

```
(defun make-list-comparator (&rest predicates)
  (labels ((tails< (l1t l2t pt)
             (let ((< (first pt))
                   (e1 (first l1t))
                   (e2 (first l2t)))
               (cond
                ((funcall < e1 e2) t)
                ((funcall < e2 e1) nil)
                ((and (null l1t) (null l2t) (null pt)) nil)
                ((or (null l1t) (null l2t) (null pt))
                 (error "crashed into the end"))
                (t (tails< (rest l1t) (rest l2t) (rest pt)))))))
    (lambda (l1 l2)
      (tails< l1 l2 predicates))))
```

And now

```
> (sort (copy-list '((1 b) (1 a) (2 D) (1 z) (1 t) (2 a) (1)))
        (make-list-comparator
         #'<
         (lambda (s1 s2)
           (string< (string s1) (string s2)))))
((1 a) (1 b) (1 t) (1 z) (2 a) (2 d) (3 n))
```

Answer (score 3):

You have basically two options:

- define a comparison function of two elements `(x0 y0)` and `(x1 y1)` that returns T if:

  - `x0 < x1`, or
  - `x0` and `x1` are equivalent **[*]** and `y0 <' y1`.

  You could also generalize this solution by defining a higher-order functions that accepts a list of test and key parameters and combines them to create a comparison function that applies them all on two values.

  **[*]** equivalence being defined as neither `a < b` or `b < a` in the general case when `<` is a user-provided comparison function.
- sort the list once to compare the respective second fields of entries, then call `stable-sort` on the result to sort according to the first field: you have to start from least significant field (changing the order of application of sorts changes the results). For example:

  ```
  ((1 c) (2 b) (0 a) (1 b))
  ```

  sort by second field `#'string<`

  ```
  ((0 a) (1 b) (2 b) (1 c))
  ```

  then stable-sort by first field `#'<`

  ```
  ((0 a) (1 b) (1 c) (2 b))    #### RES 1
  ```

  The result would be as follows by sorting by the first field first:

  ```
  ((0 a) (1 c) (1 b) (2 b))
  ```

  Then (stably) by the second:

  ```
  ((0 a) (1 b) (2 b) (1 c))    #### RES 2
  ```

  By calling `stable-sort`, when the first field of two elements are equal, the stability of the sort guarantees they will keep being sorted by their second field. You can apply `stable-sort` multiple times if you have more fields to compare.

Be careful, in Common Lisp `sort` mutates the input.